# Embed soundcloud player with url

Tags: php, html, embed

i'm actually working on a website where the users will put the soundcloud link of their tracks and there will be a player directly on the website. The problem is I have not found any solution on how to embed a soundcloud player with only the link. I can't ask my users to give me the iframe link it would not be serious i guess.

So thanks to everyone in advance !

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible sample

Comment: yes my bad. the src of the iframe is a modified specific link like this :

src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/159570672&color=%23131722&auto_play=false"

i'm searching a way to get a link like this with a track link like this : https://soundcloud.com/theweeknd/heartless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I can't ask my users to give me the iframe link`. You can change an iframe `src` with javascript. Just give the `iframe` an id. Then compose the link using js and insert the user's part into the string to be assigned to `src`.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, if I were to suggest a solution it would more or less what @GetSet just typed so for the sake of not being redundant I'm not gonna contribute further

Comment: thanks for your answer ! yes i actually store the link in a database and put it in the src with php but for a soundcloud player the src link isn't the link of the tracks. it's a modified specific link like this :

src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/159570672&color=%23131722&auto_play=false"

i don't know how to get a link like this

Comment: @TomSabatier a php wrapper for the soundcloud api might just solve your other  concern of transforming the link for the player. Check out these links. However do more research too. https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud       ,          https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#resolving